# Spring @autowire doesnot work inside @component

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, spring-annotations, jmesa

I have a spring annotated class defined below

```
@component   
public class FormFilter extends DroplistFilterEditor{    

   @Autowire   
   private PersonService personService;

   @Override
   protected List<Option> getOptions()
   {
      List<Option> options = new ArrayList<Option>();
      try {
         String fieldName = getColumn().getProperty();
         List<StudyListView> studyList = null;
         studyList=personService.findList();
         for(StudyListView study:studyList){
           options.add(new Option(study.getId(),study.getDesc()));
         }       
     } catch (Exception ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
     }
     return options;
   }
}
```

I am trying to call this class from jsp to display a dropdown list on page load. We are using jMesa for table rendering.

While the application is deploying the above class gets loaded but while it is called from jsp the personService object is null. The autowiring is not happening.

I am new to Spring MVC as well as jMesa. Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

AppConfig File

```
@Configuration
@Import({
AppTilesConfig.class,
AppWebConfig.class,
AppJpaConfig.class,
})

@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
    "com.service",
    "com.controller",
    "com.web.ui",
  })
public class AppConfig {
    // This class is a root to import all dependent configurations.
}
```

And the for the Spring mvc (AppWebConfig) i have below class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class AppWebConfig {

@Bean
public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource()
{
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new     ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    String[] resources = {"classpath:messages"};
    messageSource.setBasenames(resources);
    return messageSource;
  }
}
```

Find the jsp code where the FormFilter is called on page load

```
<jmesa:springTableFacade id="imageTableId" items="${imageList}"
                    stateAttr="restore" var="item" exportTypes="" editable="false" rowFilter=""
                    toolbar="com.bar.FullPaginationToolBar">
                    <jmesa:htmlRow uniqueProperty="rowId" rowRenderer="com.bar.CustomHtmlRowRenderer"><jmesa:htmlTable><jmesa:htmlColumn property="study" style="white-space: nowrap" title="Study" editable="false" filterable="true" filterEditor="com.web.ui.FormFilter" sortable="true" /></jmesa:htmlRow></jmesa:springTableFacade>
```

Comment: Thta code wan't compile. Because the anotations must start with a uppercase letter. Show code of `PersonService` implementation. Is `component-scan` activated for the packages?

Comment: The most probable reason is that you create the instance of the class yourself, instead of getting it from Spring. Show us the REAL, compiling code, and show us how you get an instance of this class.

Comment: @Jens If you see the code the PersonService is uppercase. component-scan is activated for the packages.

Comment: @Usha But `@autowired` in your posted code is lower case! Add the PersonService implemenatation to your question

Comment: @Jens Sorry that was typo error. In my code it is uppercase.

Comment: @JBNizet  Added few more configuration files. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Not much. Your code still doesn't compile, and we still don't know where and how this FormFilter class is used and instantiated.